# HWIOAuthBundle custom service provider arguments

Tags: symfony, service, oauth, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I'm trying to set up `HWIOAuthBundle` to work with `FOSUserBundle`.

While making my own User Provider that extends `FOSUBUserProvider`, I did the following:

```
namespace Naroga\Reader\CommonBundle\Service\Security;

use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider;
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;

class NarogaUserProvider extends FOSUBUserProvider {

    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response) {

        [...]

    }

}
```

My services.yml is as follows:

```
naroga.reader.common.security.user_provider:
    class: Naroga\Reader\CommonBundle\Service\Security\NarogaUserProvider
    arguments: [ @fos_user.user_manager ]
```

Whenever I run the program, I get the following error:

`Argument 2 passed to HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider::__construct() must be of the type array, none given, called in`

This makes great sense, because `FOSUBUserProvider::__construct`'s signature is `public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, array $properties)`.

I have no idea what to define as being my second parameter to my service so it can override `FOSUBUserProvider`. I've been googling it and all I find is people with the same question, no answers.

I'd be forever grateful to the gentle soul that tells me what the second parameter must be in order to comply with FOSUBUserProvider's signature.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is used for mapping.
As I understand, this is the name corresponding OAuth service and name of field in your entity.

For example, you can send them as follows:

```
naroga.reader.common.security.user_provider:
    class: Naroga\Reader\CommonBundle\Service\Security\NarogaUserProvider
    arguments: [ @fos_user.user_manager, { facebook: facebookId, twitter: twitterId } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to pass also some additional arguments, let's say fire an event using dispatcher which was my case, just overwrite the constructor.

```
use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseClass;

FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseClass
{
    /**
     * @var EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    private $eventDispatcher;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param UserManagerInterface $userManager FOSUB user provider.
     * @param array $properties Property mapping.
     * @param EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher
     */
    public function __construct(
        UserManagerInterface $userManager,
        array $properties,
        EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        $this->userManager     = $userManager;
        $this->properties      = array_merge($this->properties, $properties);
        $this->accessor        = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }
```

And the service definition:

```
tb_user_provider:
    class: "%tb_user_provider.class%"
    arguments: [@fos_user.user_manager, { facebook: facebook_id }, @event_dispatcher]
```